# python Compute histogram values with a groupby panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to group data from a dataframe using dataframe and I want to compute the histogram of the grouped data :
This is my dataframe :

```
    indicator
key        
14        1
14        2
14        3
15        1
16        2
16        5
16        6
17        1
18        3
```

And I want to get this result using groupby :

```
       indicator
key        
14        1,2,3
15        1
16        2,5,6
17        1
18        3
```

and then compute the histogram of every key

Comment: Can you post raw data and code to recreate your df, looking at what you're trying to do, you're sub-selecting just 2 columns from your df and then trying to groupby on a single column which now no longer exists which won't work. Can you show what your desired result is. Additionally a groupby object simply contains metadata about how to group the df, you need to call some aggregate func like `sum` for instance

Comment: I want to compute the histogram of the indicators for each application that's why I needed to group the data by application

Comment: Again I ask for raw data and code, you've edited your code to possibly fix a typo but the fact remains a `groupby` object doesn't yield a Series or DataFrame until you perform an aggregation function, you've not stated which line the error occurs

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.histogram` cannot deal with the array in an array. You need to format your data like this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
dataf = pd.DataFrame()
dataf['key'] = range(14,25)
dataf['indicator'] = [1,1,2,1,3,4,7,15,23,43,67]
dataf.loc[11] = [14,2]
dataf.loc[12] = [14,3]
dataf.loc[13] = [16,5]
dataf.loc[14] = [16,6]
```

Because there is no raw data provided, I can only assume data maybe can be reformatted like this.

```
In [30]: dataf
Out[30]: 
    key  indicator
0    14          1
1    15          1
2    16          2
3    17          1
4    18          3
5    19          4
6    20          7
7    21         15
8    22         23
9    23         43
10   24         67
11   14          2
12   14          3
13   16          5
14   16          6
```

`numpy.histogram` already handled the `groupby` concept so you don't need to do `groupby` function in `DataFrame`.
You just need to do `np.histogram(dff['indicator'])`

FYI, if you want to plot a histogram, you can also use [DataFrame.hist()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html)

```
dataf.indicator.hist()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Comment: I need to compute the histogram values for every key that's why I used groupby

Comment: @erija What do you mean the histogram values for every key? Do you mean you want to know how many times each key occur? Is the key continuous (i.e., treating 14 and 15 as numbers of difference by 1) or categorical (i.e., treating 14 and 15 as two distinct terms)?